# Cargo - Jetty9 - Unexpected error when trying to start the webapp

Tags: maven-2, jetty, cargo, maven-cargo, jetty-9

I'm stuck on deploying a war to a remote Jetty 9.

On the app-server side I've deployed the cargo-jetty-7-and-onwards-deployer (version 1.4.9). This component seems to be running correctly and responds with (as expected on a get request):

> HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Problem accessing /cargo-jetty-deployer/. Reason:
>       Command / is unknown Powered by Jetty://

To deploy I'm using the cargo-maven2-plugin (version 1.4.9) with this configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cargo.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>

            <container>
                <containerId>jetty9x</containerId>
                <type>remote</type>
            </container>

            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>80</cargo.servlet.port>
                    <cargo.hostname>ipgoeshere</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.protocol>http</cargo.protocol>
                </properties>
            </configuration>

            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <groupId>se.dn.nav</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nav-api</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <properties>
                        <context>/api</context>
                    </properties>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When running: `mvn cargo:deploy`

this results in the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.9:deploy (default-cli) on project nav-api: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.9:deploy failed: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Deploy-Stage/workspace/target/nav-api-1.2.war]: Response when calling http://ip:80/cargo-jetty-deployer/deploy?path=/api was: Error - Unexpected error when trying to start the webapp -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.9:deploy (default-cli) on project nav-api: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.9:deploy failed: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Deploy-Stage/workspace/target/nav-api-1.2.war]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.9:deploy failed: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Deploy-Stage/workspace/target/nav-api-1.2.war]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Deploy-Stage/workspace/target/nav-api-1.2.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.JettyRemoteDeployer.deploy(JettyRemoteDeployer.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerDeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable(DeployerDeployMojo.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:432)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Response when calling http://ip:80/cargo-jetty-deployer/deploy?path=/api was: Error - Unexpected error when trying to start the webapp

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.JettyRemoteDeployer.deploy(JettyRemoteDeployer.java:119)
    ... 25 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

And after this the build and deployment fails.

I've checked the logs on the Jetty, I've also upped the logging level to DEBUG, but there's no indication what is going wrong on the server side.

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong? 
Is there any way I can get a better error message to indicate whats going wrong?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! :)

P.s.
I've removed the ip int the log.

P.s.s.
The war I'm deploying is previously tested and runs fine on Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `cargo-jetty-7-and-onwards-deployer` is not compatible with Jetty 9+ (there were some lifecycle changes in Jetty 9 that cargo is likely not aware of)

Do this (to find out) ...

1. Start jetty with the following extra command line

   > java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar -Dorg.LEVEL=DEBUG -Djetty.dump.start=true
2. Check the logs, there should be tons more information, including a server state dump.
   If `cargo-jetty-deployer` is either not present or not labeled as STARTED then the deployer webapp itself failed to start.

If you feel like it, update your question with the dump and/or relevant webapp startup error logging events (not the entire log, as that is just far to noisy)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is setting the `config.home` system property to the parent directory of the `webapps` directory of Jetty.

The deployer will copy the uploaded war to the `webapps` directory and let Jetty deploy it automatically.

If `config.home` is set then the deployer will use `${config.home}/webapps`, if not then it will use `${jetty.home}/webapps` as the target directory for the war file. For me the webapps directory is configured to be `${jetty.base}/webapps` which is something different than `${jetty.home}/webapps`. Setting `${config.home}` equal to `${jetty.base}` solved the issue.